# How to use the file chooser dialog to save a file in R on macOS?

Tags: r, macos

does anyone know a solution for "choose.dir" for Mac to export my builded raster as tif data. Exchanging "file.choose" didn't work unfortunately.

See the column code below:

```r
terra::writeRaster(kmeans_raster,
  filename = base::paste0(utils::choose.dir,'/sentinel_kmeans.tif'))
```

Thank you for help!

I tried to use "file.choose" and file.creat"

I tried to use package 'rJava' --> library("rJava")
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

```
Fehler: Laden von Paket oder Namensraum für ‘rJava’: fehlgeschlagen
 .onLoad in loadNamespace() für 'rJava' fehlgeschlagen, Details:
  Aufruf: fun(libname, pkgname)
  Fehler: JVM could not be found
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  Ausführung von Kommando '/usr/libexec/java_home' ergab Status 1
2: In fun(libname, pkgname) :
  Cannot find JVM library 'NA/lib/server/libjvm.dylib'
Install Java and/or check JAVA_HOME (if in doubt, do NOT set it, it will be detected)
>
```

Comment: `paste0(utils::choose.dir,'/sentinel_kmeans.tif')` is trying to concatenate a _function_ with a string. Perhaps you mean `utils::choose.dir()`? (parens added so that the function is called and allegedly returns a string)

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
filename <- file.path(utils::choose.dir(), "sentinel_kmeans.tif")
terra::writeRaster(kmeans_raster, filename, overwrite=TRUE)
```

I do not know why you think "rJava" is relevant here. But the reason it won't load seems to be that you do not have Java installed.